# Disable Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin for UI validation.
I have a Jquery menu to select the type of transaction.
On certain menu selection there should not be any validation happening.
I am not sure if there is a way to tell Jquery validation to be disabled

I am using a following ways for the validation

1) `$.validator.addMethod()`

2) `$.validator.addClassRules()`

3) `$("#submitButton").validate({
    rules: { some rules },
    messages: { some messages }`

on click of the submit button for a particular menu selection i want the validation to be turned OFF.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons/203989#203989) should be what you're looking for: add `class="cancel"` to your submit button when the transaction type is changed to one you don't want validated. And when it's changed to a transaction type you do want validated, just remove the class.