# How to remove jquery.validate from my form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate plugin to check my form which comes in popup.

So How to remove validation for that form. i had tried this

```
$("#close_button").click(function(){
    var settings = $('form#user_form').validate().settings;
         // Modify validation settings
    $.extend(settings, {
        rules: {}
    });
    tb_remove();
});
```

I need to remove validation of my form. Help me. Thanks in advance...

**Updated Code...**

```
$("#close_button").click(function(){
     $("form#user_form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
});
```

I had also tried

```
<input type="button" class="cancel" name="close_button" id="close_button" value="Cancel">
```

I had just added class cancel to remove validation of concern form.

My method doesnt works. Help to solve this....

Comment: perhaps `ignore: ".ignore"` for ignoring `.ignore` class

Comment: please explain by example i dont know how to use ignore

Comment: Since you asked to `remove validate from form` I assume you intend to disable all validations. If so you can use onclick=`$("#'form").validate().currentForm="";` on the button.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions in this question: [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons)

```
$("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
```

Looks like what you're after.

**EDIT:** You can configure the CSS class to disable validation when you attach `validate()` to your form, like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

The example is from this question: [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons when there is submitHandler handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820647/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons-when-th)

Comment: @staytouch: you can certain try! It looks that way from the answers in that question, although I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Ur Method doesnt works My updated codes using ur script is above. Please guide me to remove jquery.validate form validation by clicking cancel button

Comment: @staytouch: see the edit in my answer. If you apply the `ignore` class to your `#close_button` element then it should ignore validation - is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

use like:

```
  <input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class of cancel to a submit button to suppress the validation

e.g

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

See the jQuery Validator documentation of this feature here: Skipping validation on submit

EDIT:

The above technique has been deprecated and replaced with the formnovalidate attribute.

```
<input formnovalidate="formnovalidate" type="submit" value="Save" />
```