# Disable jQuery validation with class = cancel on button not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

```
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

I have two submit buttons Back and Continue, when i am clicking Back i don't want jQuery to validate the form.

Why jQuery validation not canceled when i set `class = cancel` ?

```
<button name="submit" class="cancel" value="Back">Back</button>
```

Any thoughts?

similar thing here [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons)

Comment: can you show some code and the markup accompanying this?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in the unobtrusive framework.  See :http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7964   They claim that it works if you use the Ajax.BeginForm(...) vs the Html.BeginForm(...), but that did not work for me either.  The only way I got it to work was to add this script before any unobtrusive jQuery files like so:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ":hidden .ignore" 
});
```

and you must not use any HttpPostAttribute'ed methods.  I don't understand why myself, but it just did not work from me when I used postback methods.  =(  Hope this helps

REF: http://forums.asp.net/p/1752906/4751939.aspx/1?Re+MVC+3+How+to+bypass+client+side+validation

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about which jQuery plugin are you using at this example?

If you want to reset form, then you can use Validator method resetForm( )

I suggested that you are usign [this](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) plugin

Comment: he is indeed using that. this plugin has got the aforesaid functionality

Comment: @Joper try to check validator.cancelSubmit or set validator.cancelSubmit = true

Answer (score 0):

If the submit button is part of an Ajax form, there is an issue with jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js ignoring the cancel class.  See http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7964.

Comment: So is it bug in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`?

Comment: in my case i have just simple post form(not ajax-post) but looks like `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` still affecting that?

Comment: No, the issue is only on an Ajax submit.  It has no effect on a standard post.