# How to override jQuery validate when deleting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons)

I've got a form that is successfully using jQuery Validation to check the fields on a form creating/editing an entry on my site (a Drupal node, if you really care).  I'm trying to set things up so that I get normal validation when the user clicks on the "Save" button but NOT when the user clicks on "Delete" -- there's no reason to insist on a complete form if the thing is being deleted.  I'm able to catch the invalid detection in an invalidHandler clause, but I can't find the right way to tell the form submission to continue if it was the Delete button that was clicked.  Any suggestions out there?

Comment: is this a javascript single page app or a normal plain web app??

Comment: Show us the relevant code or there's not much to do here.  There's no reason you can't avoid validation on the "delete" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference) states the following:

> To skip validation while still using a submit-button, add a class="cancel" to that input.

So, try applying that class.

Comment: Please do not link to other answers or post answers than contain nothing but a link.  Each answer should be fully self-contained.

Comment: I used your link in the close instead