# MVC3 C# Disabling the Validation Messages on Cancel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have an MVC2 C# .Net Web App.  We are using the built in MVC3 Validation using the Domain class properties  `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start From is required.")]` and in the HTML  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartFrom)`

However, when we submit the page using the Cancel button, the validation is fired stating the "Start From is Required" and therefore not exiting the page.  How can I disable the Validation on the Cancel button?  Or submit the page without firing the Validation?

Comment: Why are you POSTing when the user clicks Cancel? Perhaps you could change the button to a link?

Comment: @jrummell....I found the answer I needed. See my answer below. THx

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons)

Comment: @jrummell...agreed, that's the post I got my answer from

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override the default behaviour of the submit button i.e., Cancel button in your case.

Say you have the cancel button like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnCancel" value="cancel"/>
```

now write the jQuery to override the default behaviour

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnCancel').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //or you can return false from this method.
        //return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Karthik...that's close.  It desables the Validation, but the page doesn't submit.  When I add $('form').submit(); the page submits but also runs the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here, on Stackoverflow :)  [jQuery disable validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons)
Each of the first two answers in that link worked for me.  @Karthik, thanks for the answer.  It got me on the right track

Answer 1:

```
<input id = "theCancel" class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer 2:

```
$(function () {
    $('#theCancel').click(function (e) {
        $("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
    });
});
```

I chose answer 2 and put it in our global js file.  All of our Cancel buttons have an id of "theCancel"

Comment: Well i've just seen a similar answer in SO to add class cancel.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll probably use...class="cancel"