# Stop JQuery Validation once submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, validation

How do I not trigger validation of the following form once using

```
javascript: form.action
```

I have 2 Submit buttons first one must use `sellitem1.php` as action and not use JQuery VALIDATION but 2nd one must VALIDATE form and use action listed in the Form Action: `upload.php`.

2nd Button is working well :)

```
<form method="post" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm"
action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input  type="text" class="button_date"  name="price" id="price"
value="" size="15" />

<input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;"
name="Back" id="Back" type="submit"  value="Back" onclick="javascript:
form.action='sellitem1.php';"/>

<input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;"
name="List Item" id="submit" type="submit" value="List Item"
onClick="removeFocus()"/> </form>


<script>

$( "#UploadForm" ).validate({
       errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",   wrapper: "td",
       rules: {  price: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    range: [1.00, 500000.00]

    }   } }); </script>
```

Comment: You can have the submit buttons call javascript functions to validate. So button 1 calls validate but button 2 just does a regular submit

Comment: but 1st and 2nd submit button must use different action pages, could you please provide example ?

Comment: it's keep calling validation once pressing 1st button, 2nd button is fine. And please remember that both buttons must have different action

Comment: if button type is SUBMIT validation is triggered straight away

Comment: Add a class of `cancel` to the button that shouldn't validate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/

Comment: YES, YES, YES, please add that as a main answer I will tick green !!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.  So basically you'd call the `validate()` on `click` event on the button for which you want to run validation.

```
// Javascript

$('#Back').click(function (evt) {
    $('#UploadForm').attr('action', 'sellitem1.php');
});

$('#submit').click(function (evt) {
    removeFocus();
    return $("#UploadForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
        wrapper: "td",
        rules: {
            price: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                range: [1.00, 500000.00]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It's better practice not to embed javascript/css code inline.  You could update your html as follows (Note that I only removed your `onclick` attributes and not style):

```
<form method="post" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm"
action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <input  type="text" class="button_date"  name="price" id="price"
value="" size="15" />

    <input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;"
name="Back" id="Back" type="submit"  value="Back" />

    <input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;"
name="List Item" id="submit" type="submit" value="List Item" /> 
</form>
```

Update: Here is the fiddle showing how this works http://jsfiddle.net/M3LRd/

Comment: it doesnt work, no validation and always redirect to curentitems.php :(

Comment: that si the solution Add a class of cancel to the button that shouldn't validate. stackoverflow.com/questions/203844

Comment: @user2511459, I've added fiddle as a demo with the code in this answer.  But yes, `class="cancel"` will also work.