# Stop jQuery validation and submit the form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have jquery validation in my page which has two functionalities Submit,Search. When i click on submit, the page gets validated and once the correct values are entered the form gets submitted.

Now i have another button(Search) on the same page. When i click on that button the form again gets validated since the control submits the form. But i don't need the validation for this button.

//Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#form1").validationEngine('attach');
        });
    </script>
```

The above code makes the validation enable for both the buttons.

Is there any option to make the validation disabled on click of the `Search` button?

(Or)

Can this validation made to work `OnClick` of the button instead of submitting the form.

**Note:** This piece of code is in the `master` page.

Source: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

Comment: Did you try `$('#search').on('click', function() { $('#form1').get(0).submit(); });`

Comment: Is this should be inside this jQuery(document).ready(function (){ //Code}); ?

Comment: That would be a good idea, yes !

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203844/2744839). Note that a workaround is required in order for it to work with unobtrusive validation.

Comment: @adeneo: No,its not working.

Comment: Then try the solution from @ThinTim, adding a cancel class or using the cancelSubmit method!

Comment: Added the class too. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions further down the page on how to work around the issue introduced by the unobtrusive library?

Comment: Yes i did. But nothing helped.