# Disable client side validation with javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side-validation

Here's my form submission code:

```
$('#mainForm').submit();
```

All the solutions for disabling client side validation that I've seen have involved updating an attribute on the button that's pressed. But in my code there is no button press. The form is submitted using javascript.

How do I switch off client side validation on the client before submitting a form with code?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons especially this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879499/872395

Comment: This worked... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2879499/221683

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly, I make simple code for you,

If you want to stop submit, you can use return false in your javascript function.

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/Z9Rw2/

```
$("#buttonForm").on('click', function(e){
    return false;
    $("#mainForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Its not a button click but a drop down list change that's triggering the submission. Anyhow, I returned false from the handler but it still fires the validation. I checked the fiddle but it doesn't incorporate the validation library so its demonstrative power is somewhat diminished.

Answer (score 0):

How do I switch off client side validation ?

try this

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: That's not using Javascript.