# How to submit a form in JavaScript without triggering jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to have jQuery validation when the whole form is completed and submitted.

But when a drop down list is changed, I only want to have a POST to action so that I can get a refreshed view with updates. Say, when a state is chosen, the form post to the server side with current half-finished data, and the server returned the same page but with facilities specific to that selected state.

In this case, I want to submit the form without validation.

Like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectStates', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var $form = $('#formEdit');
    
    $form.bypassValidate();
    $form.submit();
});
```

So what is the right way to `$form.bypassValidate();`?

We know in submit buttons, we can add a `formnovalidate` tag to bypass validation. But how can we do this in JavaScript?

---

## Update with my solution

Okay, I looked through the post [jQuery Validation plugin: disable validation for specified submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons?lq=1) again. And alas, there is a solution hidden in one of the answers.

`formnovalidate` does not apply here if I need to bypass validation in JavaScript.

All we need is to call `cancelSubmit` (which should be named `cancelValidate` IMHO) on the `validator`, which is bound to our jQuery form.

So my code on the `select` input is:

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectStates', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var $form = $('#formEdit');

    $form.data('validator').cancelSubmit = true;
    $form.submit();
});
```

Comment: This seems like a misuse of forms. Can you separate out the select into its own form that does what you want or use an ajax call to dynamically change the page contents?

Comment: *"Is there something like a `formnovalidate` tag, which can be placed on a button to submit the form without validation?"*  Exactly:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/203989/594235

Comment: Sparky, I won't say it is a duplicate question. Nowhere in that SO question did I find how to bypass validation when submitting the form in JavaScript. We could not use "formnovalidate" on the drop down list.