# Jquery validation plugin submit without validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin. When I click the 'My btn' button the form needs to submit without validation. Even if the `title` is empty it should be able submit by only clicking the 'My btn' button. Is there any way to do this?

```html
<form class="callBkfrm" method="POST" action="/my_action">
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <button class='btn' type="button">My btn</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(".myFrm").validate({
  rules: {
    title: {
      required: true
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: At the bottom of the SO about [jquery-validate](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).  Edit: seems to be outdated, see https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-skipping-validation-on-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jquery-validate [reference](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-skipping-validation-on-submit)*:

---

**Skipping validation on submit**

To skip validation while still using a submit-button, add the attribute `formnovalidate` to that input:

```
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Cancel">
```

This used to work by adding `class="cancel"` to the input, this is now deprecated.

[Demo for the cancel button](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html)

*copied here for reference

Comment: Duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/203844/594235